# compile error: ifstream::open only accepts string values in quotes "" and not string variables

Tags: c++, g++, fstream, ifstream

Does `open` function have some sort of restriction as to what kind of string value is passed in?

```
ifstream file;
string filename = "output.txt";
file.open(filename);
```

I tried to pass a string value with a string variable, but when it tries to compile, the result is...

```
agent.cpp:2:20: error: ofstream: No such file or directory
agent.cpp: In function ‘std::string readingline(std::string)’:
agent.cpp:11: error: aggregate ‘std::ifstream file’ has incomplete type and cannot be     defined
agent.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
agent.cpp:44: error: aggregate ‘std::ofstream writefile’ has incomplete type and cannot be defined
```

On the other hand, when I just pass a string value in quotes like "filename.txt" , it compile fine and runs fine.

```
ifstream file;
file.open("output.txt");
```

Why is this the case?

Is there a way to solve this problem?

Comment: did you try to pass a pointer to a char array?

Comment: See [Why does (i|o)fstream take a const char* parameter for a file name?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5972151/why-does-iofstream-take-a-const-char-parameter-for-a-file-name)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sadly, this is how the constructor and `open` of `std::(i|o)fstream` are defined by the standard. Use `file.open(filename.c_str())`.

Some standard libraries provide an extension that allows `std::string` as a parameter, e.g. Visual Studio.

Comment: Thank you  Xeo. Using `file.open(filename.c_str())` worked out.

Comment: It is not an extension anymore, but in compliance with the C++11 standard.

Comment: @Bo: Wait, we got those in C++11? I must have missed that. *goes to skim through the standard*

Comment: I suppose the reason why `const char*` was preferred over `std::string` is that filenames, by (POSIX) definition can never contain embedded nulls. Saying `file.open(fname.c_str())` makes that explicit to the programmer

Answer (score 1):

I think your error messages may be unrelated to the code in question, but `open` takes a C-style `const char*` and not a C++ `string`. You'll need to use `filename.c_str()` in the call to make it work correctly.

Comment: Thanks Mark B for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

I got the problem to go away by including `fstream` and passing `filename.c_str()` instead of just `filename`.

The message about an incomplete type is because you are missing a header (probably anyway, you didn't show a full example).

And `open` takes a c-style string, not the `string` class.