# Ofstream, use variable to the name

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, ofstream

Hello for all people...

Sorry for my english, but speak spanish...

In this week, study and work for this proyect, I want create a software to make files(.us)...

**Example**

```
char name[50]; //Or string
cin>>name;

ofstream PlayerPawn("D:\\UDK\\UDK_XXX\\Development\\Src\\" + name+"\\Classes\\_PlayerPawn.us");
```

But the compiler has error in the **Operator binary plus**

Any alternative, examples or something for create the file in specific directory

Good bye and Thx!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either side of `operator+` must be a `std::string`<sup>1</sup> for `operator+` to concatenate strings:

```
string name;
cin >> name;

ofstream PlayerPawn("D:\\UDK\\UDK_XXX\\Development\\Src\\" + name + "\\Classes\\_PlayerPawn.us");
```

And use `std::string` for this stuff; with `std::string` there's no danger of buffer overflows that you get with `char*`.

---

<sup>1</sup> Actually it just needs to be a class type that supports `operator+`, not specifically `std::string`, but then you have no idea what it will do.

Comment: But, change the variable to std::string but has this error...
`D:\Users\Warkanlock\Documents\Code Blocks\UDK_ProyectSimple\main.cpp|20|error: no matching function for call to 'std::basic_ofstream<char, std::char_traits<char> >::basic_ofstream(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >)'|`

Comment: @Warkanlock make sure you put `#include <string>` at the top of your code.

Comment: @Warkanlock your error is coming from somewhere else where you are using an `std::ofstream`. You'll need to paste the rest of your code.

Comment: @Warkanlock the constructor for `ofstream` takes a `const char*`, not a `string`. Put the `"..." + nombre + "..."` in parentheses, then after the end of the parentheses call `c_str` on the string. Like this: `ofstream PlayerPawn(("D:\\UDK\\UDK_XXX\\Development\\Src\\" + nombre + "\\Classes\\_PlayerPawn.us").c_str());`

Comment: Here is another [Stack Overflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32332/why-dont-the-stdfstream-classes-take-a-stdstring) about this oddity. Good catch Seth.

Comment: @Matt [Actually I asked the exact same question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5972151/why-does-iofstream-take-a-const-char-parameter-for-a-file-name) a long time ago too :)

Comment: Thx! men! I REALY WORK THIS!!

Ps: When finish make this software, i send the exe for MP hhaha Thx realy!

Answer (score 3):

I believe you want `name` to be a `std::string` - otherwise, `name + [suffix]` will try to add the  suffix string to the array and will not compile. If you really want to keep the name as an array, you should use [strcat](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strcat/) to append the strings together.

Comment: But, to change de Variable to String and has same error!


`D:\Users\Warkanlock\Documents\Code Blocks\UDK_ProyectSimple\main.cpp|20|error: no matching function for call to 'std::basic_ofstream<char, std::char_traits<char> >::basic_ofstream(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >)'|`

Comment: Well, that's not the same error - you need to `#include <iostream>` to define what an "ofstream" is

Comment: Ya, this include that include in this file :o

Comment: See my comment at the tail of @Seth Carnegie's answer